# A was persuaded away from B

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of a phrase “A was persuaded away from B” here?

> Thirty years later, George Miller, the Australian director of the
>   original trilogy, **was persuaded away from** films about tap-dancing
>   penguins to revive the brand. In “Fury Road” he has given us villains
>   for the Justin Bieber generation, and they are a very peculiar bunch
>   indeed. (Economist)

(link address: http://www.economist.com/blogs/prospero/2015/05/new-film-mad-max-fury-road)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that someone persuaded him to try something else than what he had been doing. The "dancing penguins" is a reference to the *HAPPY FEET* movies, which he directed.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Feet

Comment: In your explanation, does someone include himself? Don't you think 'something' should replace 'someone' in your explanation? (I think someone makes the range of the cause too narrow)

Comment: I think if he talked himself into it, one might use "became convinced" or "convinced himself" or "decided", rather than the passive "was persuaded".

Comment: @InfimumMaximum: Note that persuation implies reasoning or argument to convince someone of something, which can only be done by a person. (Or, in afntasy/scifi, other intelligent beings)